# Does room temperature matter when dripping?

Tags: drip-brew, temperature

When hand dripping coffee in Winter, some water vanishes into mist. We obviously need to go quick before the water temperature drops too much. Also, a cold room tends to cause more mist, making hard to see the coffee ground while dripping.

Is there a recommended room temperature for "better" drip? Better here may mean higher quality drink result, or just more convenient ways of dripping.

The question is more about hand-dripping, but it could matter with machines as well.

Comment: As "brewing" itself is a chemical process, it should. However, with my limited knowledge of chemistry, I cannot comment on this —which contradicts to what I'm doing right now :).

Comment: I don't know anything about "dripping", but the rates of chemical reactions are always dependent on temperature. Generally they speed up with higher temperatures.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that room temperature can have an affect on the final outcome of your coffee if the room your in is cold enough. Probably not so much if your sitting in a warm room.

I say this because to get a full extraction from your coffee, your water should be between [90°C - 96°C](https://bettercoffeeathome.com/make-better-coffee-home/) and being in a cold environment can cool that water rather quickly.

If you're interested in calculating the speed at which water cools, here is some "light" reading that goes over newton's law of cooling if you're interested: http://stanwagon.com/public/evaporationportmannwagonmier.pdf

Not sure what the ideal room temperature would be though. I would guess one that would allow your water to stay hot enough for the whole brew time.